# Multiple forms same page submit only one ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page that dynamically create forms from rows in the DB.  Each table row contains a form with a submit button to delete a record from the DB.  I can't seem to figure out how to pick the current form to submit.  They all have different IDs, but how does the script know what form the use clicks on?

```
<form name="myForm" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="sales">                          
<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
<i class="fe fe-trash-2"></i></button>
</form>

<form name="myForm" id="2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="sales">                          
<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
<i class="fe fe-trash-2"></i></button>
</form>

$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    var thisForm = this.form;

        $.ajax({
            url: "delete_do.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: $(thisForm).serialize(),

        });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Stan. You can determine the id of the form clicked using `form.id`; so `thisForm.id` or `this.form.id` should work fine. However I would suggest you use a submit event on the form rather than a click event on the submit button.

Comment: can you start me off with a an example using my code?  New to jquery.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the snippet below. Note that since there're fields named `id`, `form.id` or `this.id` will not give the value of the `id` of the form. Hence `$('form').attr('id')`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form[name="myForm"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //form ID ** cannot use form.id or this.id 
    //because you've named a field id .. name="id" **
    var formID = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log( formID );
    //form Data
    console.log( $(this).serialize() ); //or
    console.log( $(this).serializeArray() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="1">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="sales">                          
<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
<i class="fe fe-trash-2"></i></button>
</form>

<form name="myForm" id="2">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="sales">                          
<button name="command" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete">
<i class="fe fe-trash-2"></i></button>
</form>
```